# Xamarin.Android app crashes after user update on play store

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, crash

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28308953/xamarin-android-after-user-updates-app-it-crashes)

A workaround I found was to uninstall and re-install the app.
However, it may be difficult to convince users on the play store to do that, as they may not read the update change-log before downloading. (e.g. auto-update).

I narrowed down the cause to:

```
09-28 21:41:26.011: I/MonoDroid(6923): UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
09-28 21:41:26.047: I/MonoDroid(6923): Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageButton ---> Java.Lang.Exception: Exception of type 'Java.Lang.Exception' was thrown. ---> Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f010127 a=-1}
09-28 21:41:26.047: I/MonoDroid(6923):    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
09-28 21:41:26.047: I/MonoDroid(6923):    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
09-28 21:41:26.047: I/MonoDroid(6923):   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <9ab6e5aa0dab475cab5597fa4269890c>:0 
09-28 21:41:26.047: I/MonoDroid(6923):   at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00089] in <5e50b69e5a0e439f924bf0f2e8fcd52c>:0 
09-28 21:41:26.047: I/MonoDroid(6923):   at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualVoidMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x0005d] in <5e50b69e5a0e439f924bf0f2e8fcd52c>:0 
09-28 21:41:26.047: I/MonoDroid(6923):   at Android.App.Activity.SetContentView (System.Int32 layoutResID) [0x00022] in <f051fcdec18c4806998a5576ba788eec>:0 
09-28 21:41:26.047: I/MonoDroid(6923):   at mypackagename.MainActivity+<OnCreate>d__33.MoveNext () [0x0004d] in <467e37befb3d49c788d8cebf5dfb11a2>:0 
09-28 21:41:26.047: I/MonoDroid(6923): --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
09-28 21:41:26.047: I/MonoDroid(6923):   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <9ab6e5aa0dab475cab5597fa4269890c>:0 
09-28 21:41:26.047: I/MonoDroid(6923):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_0 (System.Object state) [0x00000] in <9ab6e5aa0dab475cab5597fa4269890c>:0 
09-28 21:41:26.047: I/MonoDroid(6923):   at Android.App.SyncContext+<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Post>b__0 () [0x00000] in <f051fcdec18c4806998a5576ba788eec>:0 
09-28 21:41:26.047: I/MonoDroid(6923):   at Java.Lang.Thread+RunnableImplementor.Run () [0x00008] in <f051fcdec18c4806998a5576ba788eec>:0 
09-28 21:41:26.047: I/MonoDroid(6923):   at Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this) [0x00008] in <f051fcdec18c4806998a5576ba788eec>:0 
09-28 21:41:26.047: I/MonoDroid(6923):   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:471f272e-f7ed-4fdc-805d-59ce5a399fd4 (intptr,intptr)
09-28 21:41:26.047: I/MonoDroid(6923):   --- End of managed Java.Lang.RuntimeException stack trace ---
09-28 21:41:26.047: I/MonoDroid(6923): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageButton
```

Old apk was built using Xamarin.VisualStudio_4.5.0.486 on VS Community 2015.3
New apk was build using Xamarin.VisualStudio_4.6.3.4 on VS Community 2017
both apk targets Nougat 7.0, and minimum ICS 4.0.3

There was no change whatsoever to my axml layout files. That is also evident because after re-installation, the ImageButton inflates without any problem.

How can this issue be resolved?

Comment: Are all Play Store based upgrades failing? If so, it might be that a custom theme is incorrectly setup, either the theme is not applied to the Activity or referenced attributes are not properly set in all your themes. An uninstall/reinstalled flushes the application cache and thus your app runs fine then. Without looking at your entire app, I could not determine if this is the root cause of the issue, but I seen this before.

Comment: @SushiHangover You were right. I store the users chosen theme as an integer value to SharedPreferences. I retrieve and apply it in OnCreate. However, the root cause is that Xamarin decided to change the integer value of my theme, so the stored value in Sharedpreferences after an update, no longer corresponds to any of the available theme. This causes any widget that relies on a theme to fail to inflate. I've resolved the issue. Now I understand that the integer values on Resources aren't really constant. They may change when re-installing xamarin or visual studio.

Comment: If you resolved the issue would you mind writing an asnwer with the steps / decisions that lead to resolving the issue?